# Shiny app does not start anymore

Tags: shiny

The problem with my shiny app is that it does not start anymore. It can be accessed by this link: https://buchmann.shinyapps.io/RevealedTechnologicalAdvantage/

It always worker properly but when I tried to start it today I got the error message:

```
An error has occurred

The application failed to start.

Loading required package: RCurl
Loading required package: bitops
Error in guess(varying) : 
  failed to guess time-varying variables from their names
Calls: local ... source -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> reshape -> guess
Execution halted
```

I get the same when I start it in RStudio

I deployed it again but the result was the same.

Can anybody tell me what the error message means?

Thanks a lot!
Tobias

#

here is the code:

## ui.r

```
require(rCharts)

options(RCHART_LIB = 'polycharts')

l = c("Electrical machinery, apparatus, energy",
      "Audio-visual technology",
      "Telecommunications",
      "Digital communication",
      "Basic communication processes",
      "Computer technology",
      "IT methods for management",
      "Semiconductors",
      "Optics",
      "Measurement",
      "Analysis of biological materials",
      "Control",
      "Medical technology",
      "Organic fine chemistry",
      "Biotechnology",
      "Pharmaceuticals",
      "Macromolecular chemistry, polymers",
      "Food chemistry",
      "Basic materials chemistry",
      "Materials, metallurgy",
      "Surface technology, coating",
      "Micro-structural and nano-technology",
      "Chemical engineering",
      "Environmental technology",
      "Handling",
      "Machine tools",
      "Engines, pumps, turbines",
      "Textile and paper machines",
      "Other special machines",
      "Thermal processes and apparatus",
      "Mechanical elements",
      "Transport",
      "Furniture, games",
      "Other consumer goods",
      "Civil engineering")

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

headerPanel("RTA by 'Schmoch field' Germany and Turkey"),

  sidebarPanel(
        selectInput(inputId = "field",
                label = "Select field",
                choices = l,
                selected = "Electrical machinery, apparatus, energy")
  ),

  mainPanel(
        showOutput("chart2", "polycharts"),
        showOutput("chart1", "polycharts")
  )
))
```

## server.r

```
share_share_de <- read.csv("share_share_de.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",", check.names = FALSE)

share_share_tr <- read.csv("share_share_tr.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",", check.names = FALSE)

require(rCharts)

options(RCHART_WIDTH = 800)

l = c("Electrical machinery, apparatus, energy",
      "Audio-visual technology",
      "Telecommunications",
      "Digital communication",
      "Basic communication processes",
      "Computer technology",
      "IT methods for management",
      "Semiconductors",
      "Optics",
      "Measurement",
      "Analysis of biological materials",
      "Control",
      "Medical technology",
      "Organic fine chemistry",
      "Biotechnology",
      "Pharmaceuticals",
      "Macromolecular chemistry, polymers",
      "Food chemistry",
      "Basic materials chemistry",
      "Materials, metallurgy",
      "Surface technology, coating",
      "Micro-structural and nano-technology",
      "Chemical engineering",
      "Environmental technology",
      "Handling",
      "Machine tools",
      "Engines, pumps, turbines",
      "Textile and paper machines",
      "Other special machines",
      "Thermal processes and apparatus",
      "Mechanical elements",
      "Transport",
      "Furniture, games",
      "Other consumer goods",
      "Civil engineering")

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

output$chart2 <- renderChart({

FIELD = as.character (which (l == input$field))

sub <-  share_share_tr [, c ("Prio_Year", FIELD)]

colnames (sub) <- c("Prio_Year", "value")

p2 <- rPlot(value ~ Prio_Year, type = 'line', data = sub)

 p2$guides(y = list(min = 0, title = ""))

 p2$guides(y = list(title = ""))

 p2$addParams(height = 300, dom = 'chart2', title = "Turkey")

return(p2)
   })

 output$chart1 <- renderChart({

FIELD = as.character (which (l == input$field))

 sub <-  share_share_de [, c ("Prio_Year", FIELD)]

 colnames (sub) <- c("Prio_Year", "value")

 p2 <- rPlot(value ~ Prio_Year, type = 'line', data = sub)

 p2$guides(y = list(min = 0, title = ""))

p2$guides(y = list(title = ""))

p2$addParams(height = 300, dom = 'chart1', title = "Germany")

return(p2)
     })  
 })
```

Comment: Please include some sample code and perhaps someone can spot a mistake and help you further.

Comment: looks like an error in the guess function, not shiny. Look and see if your code still works outside of shiny.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I get exactly the same error if I start in Rstudio. Could this be linked to a package upgrade?

Comment: @Tobias thats what i would guess. Use ?guess from the console and see if there are any notes in the documentation, or google-fu and see if there are any other users with the same problem